# Laravel 4 form model binding Form::select

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

OK after reading the documentation: http://four.laravel.com/docs/html#form-model-binding

I have a form that looks something like this:

```
{{ Form::model($profile, array('action' => 'ProfilesController@edit', $profile->user_id, 'files' => true)) }}
{{ Form::select('gender', array('0' => 'What gender are you?', '1' => 'Male', '2' => 'Female'), array('class' => 'span12')) }}
{{ From::close() }}
```

My problem is: model binding does not work with Form::select, works great with text input. What am I doing wrong??

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your 3rd parameter in the select needs to be the selected value:

```
{{ Form::select('gender', array('0' => 'What gender are you?', '1' => 'Male', '2' => 'Female'), $profile->gender) }}
```

I know it kinda defeats the purpose of model binding but it will actually work. Other issue of course is that now you've lost your class!

But if we have a quick look at the api:

```
select( string $name, array $list = array(), string $selected = null, array $options = array() )
```

We see that you can pass your options array as the 4th argument.

Therefore, the working code is:

> {{ Form::select('gender', array('0' => 'What gender are you?', '1' =>
>   'Male', '2' => 'Female'), $profile->gender, array('class' =>
>   'span12')) }}

Answer (score 6):

kJamesy is right, the third parameter must be the selected value, but if you set it to null, the form model binding will set default value.

```
{{ Form::model($profile, array('action' => 'ProfilesController@edit', $profile->user_id, 'files' => true)) }}
{{ Form::select('gender', array('0' => 'What gender are you?', '1' => 'Male', '2' => 'Female'), null, array('class' => 'span12')) }}
{{ From::close() }}
```